# Combining a text search and a lookup table

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of strings (descriptions of errors manually entered by personnel) (A2:A1000) that I'd like to search for specific words (to create categories based on the description), and based on the words found, input a specific case value (a category label) into a second column (B2:B1000). Currently this is being handled by nested if statements of the form

```
B2=if(isnumber(search("Flag Word 1",A2)),"Case Word 1", if(isnumber(search("Flag Word 2",A2)),"Case Word 2", ...))
```

Obviously for a large number of flag/case words, this gets messy pretty quickly. I'd like to be able to create a lookup table, have excel search column A for words in the lookup table, and return the corresponding value, but I'm not sure if this is possible - it doesn't seem that way without resorting to VBA. Are there any alternative methods to achieving the same result?

Thanks,

~P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an array formula like this one (has to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter):-

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,A2)),(ROW($D$2:$D$4)-ROW($D$1)))))
```

It assumes that there is a list of keywords in D2:D4, and will give you the first one in the list which is contained in the string in A2. You could change MIN to MAX to get the last match.

[image]

Comment: use `=INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MIN(...` if you have a different case word for each keyword...